# Android GCM Crashes App when Push Notification is pressed from Notification Tray

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM to implement a chat application. I have a custom push receiver extending GcmListenerService. When I press on the push notification if the application is in the background, the app crashes. Here is the code that handles the notification when the app is in the background

```
 // verifying whether the app is in background or foreground
            if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "App is not in background");

                // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
                Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.ACTION_PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
                pushNotification.putExtra("type", Config.PUSH_TYPE_CHATROOM);
                pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
                pushNotification.putExtra("chat_room_id", chatRoomId);
                sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

                // play notification sound
                NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils();
                notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "App is in background");
                // app is in background. show the message in notification try
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatRoomActivity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("chat_room_id", chatRoomId);
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, user.getName() + " : " + message.getMessage(), message.getCreatedAt(), resultIntent);
            }
```

And the NotificationUtils is a custom class with handles notifications. Here is the showNotificationMessage method:

```
 public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
// notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher1;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    0,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new     NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);  
Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

I followed other questions which specified what should be added to the manifest file. I added them all. Here is also a snippet of the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    <permission
    android:name="de.hassib.ble_heart_rate_test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="de.hassib.ble_heart_rate_test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="de.hassib.ble_heart_rate_test.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Receiver in application:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="de.hassib.ble_heart_rate_test" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Service:

```
        <service
        android:name=".service.MyGcmPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".service.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are making that validation because the actions has to be set in the Notification builder with a PendingIntent and no matter if is i background or not.

I mean something like this:

```
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

But you can verify the `getApplicationContext()` because it is not available when the app has been killed.

Comment: I do use pendingIntent in the notificationUtils class which the method calls. I edited the question and added the snippet with the notification handling.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the icon you set to your notification, since it is too large. You should resize your icon like this:

- ldpi: 48x48
- mdpi: 64x64
- hdpi: 96x96
- xhdpi: 128x128
- xxhdpi: 192x192
- xxxhdpi: 256x256

If I use the icon sizes mentioned above, it works great.